# Rudin exercise 2.11

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In exercise 11 of chapter 2, Rudin asks whether $d(x,y) = |x-2y|$ is a metric. It certainly isn't: I can find an $x$ such that $d(x,x) \neq 0$ (just take $x = 1$ and values of $x$ and $y$ that are not equal for which $d(x,y) = 0$. It is similarly not symmetric.

However, I cannot figure out how to prove or disprove the triangle inequality, which would state that
$$
d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y) 
$$
or
$$
|x-2y| \leq |x-2z| + |z-2y|.
$$
This property is almost surely false, but I cannot think of how to go about disproving it. Is there a systematic way of finding a counterexample?

Comment: $y=1$, $z=2y$ and $x=4y$, then the right side is $0$, while the left is $2$.

Comment: "However, I cannot figure out how to prove or disprove the triangle inequality"  Well.... you don't *have* to.  Since the axioms $d(x,y) = 0\iff x=y$ fails, it's not a metric.  And if it's not a metric you are done.  It won't magically turn back into a metric if you go home for an early lunch.  .....Also just because something is not a metric doesn't necessarily mean the triangle inequality fails.  Hypothetically the T.I. can hold for a non-metric.  (Not in this case but....)

Comment: Once one axiom breaks, it's all over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x-2y$ and $x-2z$ and $z-2y$ are all non-negative then the inequality is $$(x-2y)\le (x-2z)+(z-2y)=(x-2y)-z,$$ which is false if $z>0.$

So it suffices that $z>0$ and $x\ge 2y$ (so $x-2y\ge 0$) and $x\ge 2z$ (so $x-2z\ge 0$) and $z\ge 2y$ (so $z-2y\ge 0$), which in summary is $$x\ge 2z>z\ge 2y.$$ E.g. $x=2z>0=y.$

As others have said, $d$ fails to be a metric if any one of the three conditions for being  a metric fails.

Answer (score 2):

First off if *any* axiom fails.... then it's not a metric.  You are done, you don't even have to *think* about the other axioms.  Go home.  Have an early lunch. You are done!

Second, if something isn't a metric that only means at least one axiom fails.  Hypothetically for all we know, the triangle inequality *does* hold.  It's still not a metric because $d(x,x)\ne 0$ for $x\ne 0$.  All the *other* axioms might hold for all we know.  (THey don't but... in theory they could.)

But.... okay, lets disprove (or prove) the triangle inequality.  It's good practice.

TO find a counter example we need.

Case 1:  $x \ge 2y$; $y\ge 2z$ and so $x \ge 2z$.

We need $|x - 2z| > |x-2y| + |y-2z|$ or

$x - 2z > x-2y + y-2z$ or $

$0 > -y$.  So ... we can to that  $z = 0; y=1; x= 3$. then $|x-2z| = 3$ but $|x-2y|+|y-2z|=1+1=2$.

Case 2: $x\ge 2y; y< 2z$ but $x\ge 2z$

We need $|x-2z| > |x-2y| + |y-2z|$ or

$x - 2z > x -2y +2z -y$ or

$3y > 4z$  We can do that.  Let $z=2$ and $y=3$ and $x=3459$.  THen $|x-2z| = 3455$ while $|x-2y|+|y-2z|= |3453| + |3-4| = 3454$.

Case 3:  well... you get the idea.... and as I said at the beginning, we only needed one counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=5, y=1$ and $z=2$. Then the inequality fails.